# Reorder a list based on example list

Tags: list, haskell

I would like to know how to reorder a list of lists based on an example list.
Here is an example to clarify my question:

```
["Foo", "Bar", "Something"]
```

That is example list, now I want to reorder the list shown below, looking only at the heads of each list inside it:

```
[["Something", "one", "two", "three"], ["Foo", "four", "five", "six"], 
["Bar", "seven", "eight", "nine"]]
```

to this:

```
[["Foo", "four", "five", "six"], ["Bar", "seven", "eight", "nine"],
["Something", "one", "two", "three"]]
```

Thanks

Edit:

I've tried mapping a swap function that swaps two elements, but that won't work because I am dealing here with two lists.

Comment: Nice example of input/output, but: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What do you mean by _reorder_? What is the criterion according to which you want to swap the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a very brute approach:

```
Prelude> let a = [["Something", "one", "two", "three"], ["Foo", "four", "five", "six"], ["Bar", "seven", "eight", "nine"]]
Prelude> let b = ["Foo", "Bar", "Something"]
Prelude> concatMap (\y -> filter (\(x:xs) -> x == y)  a) b
[["Foo","four","five","six"],["Bar","seven","eight","nine"],["Something","one","two","three"]]
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you're doing here?

Comment: from list `a` you filter the lists that begin with "Foo", "Bar" and "Something" and then just concat these 3 lists

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on list comprehension can be :

```
Prelude> let a = [["Something", "one", "two", "three"], ["Foo", "four", "five", "six"], ["Bar", "seven", "eight", "nine"]]
Prelude> let b = ["Foo", "Bar", "Something"]

Prelude> let c = [ y | x<-b, y<-a, x `elem` y ]

[["Foo","four","five","six"],["Bar","seven","eight","nine"],["Something","one","two","three"]]
```

you can read this chapter for more explanation on how to use list comprehension: [Lyah](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort your list according to a custom comparison. So, let's do it! The basic comparison function should look at the index a value appears in the examples list.

```
import Data.List

cmpIndex :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
cmpIndex example s1 s2 = compare (indexOf s1) (indexOf s2)
    where indexOf s = findIndex (head s ==) example
```

This is a little dangerous -- calling `head` is always a cause to pause. But let's assume you know something I don't and move on. We'll give names to our inputs to make the test more readable, then fire up ghci:

```
example = ["Foo", "Bar", "Something"]
list = [["Something", "one", "two", "three"], ["Foo", "four", "five", "six"], ["Bar", "seven", "eight", "nine"]]

*Main> sortBy (cmpIndex example) list
[["Foo","four","five","six"],["Bar","seven","eight","nine"],["Something","one","two","three"]]
```